# jQuery calling a variable that has variable inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written my javascript too much, and now the code keeps repeating itself, whereas I lack of knowledge on how to simplify matters. I have this idea of calling variable into function, but I don't know how to call this kind of function that contains dynamic variables.

Anyone got any tips on how can I achieve this?

```
var container    = '#content_container';

function container_load(){
    var data         = $(this).attr('data');
    var dataObject   = {command : data};
    var title        = '<h2 data="'+dataObject.command+'">'+
                        dataObject.command+'</h2>';

};

$(function(){
    $('nav')on.('click', 'a', function(){
        container_load();
        $(container).prepend(title);
    });
});
```

Apparently, console returned `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: dataObject`

Answer (score 1):

There is two issue is in your code

```
var container    = '#content_container';
var title;   //title should be declare as global,same as "container" variable
function container_load(dis){
    var data         = dis.attr('data');
    var dataObject   = {command : data};
    title        = '<h2 data="'+dataObject.command+'">'+
                        dataObject.command+'</h2>';

}

$(function(){
    $('nav').on('click', 'a', function(){
        container_load($(this)); //you have to pass the current element
        $(container).prepend(title); 
    });
});
```

**Demo :** [Demo](http://jsbin.com/iXOzUQOZ/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var container    = '#content_container';

function container_load(currElementId){
    var data = $("#"+currElementId).attr('data');
    return '<h2 data="'+data+'">'+data+'</h2>';
};

$(function(){
    $('nav')on.('click', 'a', function(){
         var title = container_load(this.id);
        $(container).prepend(title);
    });
});
```

Here your problem is that you cannot '**this**' in other function for that you need to pass it from your current function.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be few mistakes in your code, The scope is wrong and the data attribute is used not correctly I presume. I suppose [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EjEqK/2/) is what you wanted http://jsfiddle.net/EjEqK/2/

**HTML**

```
<nav ><a href="#" data-val="abc">aaa</a></nav>
<div id="content_container"></div>
```

**JS**

```
function container_load() {
var data = $(this).data("val");
var dataObject = { command: data };
$("#content_container").prepend('<h2 data-val="' + dataObject.command + '">' + dataObject.command + '</h2>');
};

$(function () { $('nav > a').on('click', container_load); });
```

PS: If you don't need `dataObject` for anything else, directly use `data`

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you :

```
function container_load(currElement){
var data = $(currElement).attr('data');
return '<h2 data="'+data+'">'+data+'</h2>';
}

$(function(){
var container    = '#content_container';
    $('nav')on.('click', 'a', function(){
         var title = container_load(this);
        $(container).prepend(title);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following :

```
var container = '#content_container',
    title; // make title global

function container_load() {
    var data = $(this).attr('data');
    var dataObject = { command: data };
    title = '<h2 data="' + dataObject.command + '">' + 
        dataObject.command + '</h2>';
};

$(function () {
    $('nav') on.('click', 'a', function () {
        container_load.call(this); // bind this to container_load
        $(container).prepend(title);
    });
});
```

But you could do even better :

```
$(function () {
    $('nav') on.('click', 'a', function () {
        var data = $(this).attr('data');
        $('#content_container').prepend(
            '<h2 data="' + data + '">' + data + '</h2>'
        );
    });
});
```